# Average value of a whole collection on mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to get the average value of a whole mongo collection. To be more specific, I have two date fields, let's call them beginning and end.

First of all, I need to do something like end - beginning time to get the elapsed time. After that, I want to sum all the elapsed time and get the average time.

I need this data to plot a chart. I've seen that mongoDB has some built in functions like subtract, sum and average as well. I don't know how to use them, and I also need the data in minutes so I may use some Javascript to convert it, I don't know yet but this is not the problem.

Mongoose schema:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('atendimento', {
    id: String,
    id_atendimento: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    id_cliente: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    id_user: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    user_nome: String,
    cliente_nome: String,
    id_atendente: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    atendente_nome: String,
    atendente_imagem: String,
    setor: Number,
    descricao: String,
    status: String,
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    inicio: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    fim: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    update: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

The begin is the variable called inicio and the end is the variable called fim.

At the moment I need help with these mongo functions or any other suggestions will be welcome.

Thanks in advance, hope I can get some help!

Comment: First ask a question. This is a Q&A site, not a discussion board. Second: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to run an aggregation pipeline which aggregates the whole collection using a **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline.

Within the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)**, you need to calculate the timestamp difference with **[`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/)** operator and divide the result by the number of milliseconds in a minute (60 * 1000) with **[`$divide`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/)** operator.

You will then apply the **[`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/)** operator to the above expression so that you will have your collection average.

For the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline, you can specify an `_id` value of null to calculate accumulated values for all the input documents as a whole.

Following example shows the above:

```
Atendimento.aggregate([
    { '$group': {
        '_id': null,
        'average_duration': {
            '$avg': {
                '$divide': [
                    { '$subtract': ['$fim', '$inicio'] }, 
                    60*1000
                ]
            }
        }
    } }

]).exec((err, results) => console.log(results))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to user `aggregate` function with `$subtract` function.Subtracts  two dates to return the difference in milliseconds

```
db.sales.aggregate( [ { $project: { item: 1, dateDifference: { $subtract: [ new Date(), "$date" ] } } } ] )
```

this will give you data like

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "abc", "dateDifference" : NumberLong("11713985194") }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "jkl", "dateDifference" : NumberLong("11710385194") }
```

You can change the new date to another date field you have in the database.

Then you need to use $substract and $group in aggregate function to get the desired result as you haven't posted exact schema so it's hard to write your query so you can try with following

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/

Comment: I edited the question and added the schema, I'll check what you said and try it.

Comment: Ok let know if you are unable to get the desired result.